# Propoerty File Update With Backward slash and forwardslash

Tags: java, properties

Hi I am using below code for propertyfile updation. The problem is that `//` is changing to `\/\/` and `\` is removing. I saw one Post that someone used `1.10` jar for `commons-configuration-1.10` and it is working, but I have used this but it is not working for me. Is there any other jars to avoid this.

```
PropertiesConfiguration databaseProperties;
databaseProperties = new PropertiesConfiguration("Properties.properties");
databaseProperties.setProperty("PropName", "jdbc:sqlserver://");
databaseProperties.save();
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "// is changing to // and \ is removing"?

Comment: Means Backslash(\) get removed and forwaedslash(/) updated with \/.If value is Path=jdbc:sqlserver:// Then it will become jdbc:salserver:\/\/ after update.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342231/propertiesconfiguration-using-in-property-value/50210811#50210811 this is another old thread about the same.May be it will help you.

Comment: Instead of writing // in quotes, you can take help of File.separator like "jdbc:sqlserver:"+File.separator

Comment: if I use File.separator then it changing forwardslash(//) to backslash(\\).