# Single Backslash Changing to Doublebackslash in Property file

Tags: java, properties

Hi this post is related to my old post. But in this I have achieved much.
I am using `FileBasedConfigurationBuilder` class of Apache common configuration API for updating property file in java. Below is my code:

```
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration>(
                PropertiesConfiguration.class)
                        .configure(new Parameters().properties().setFileName("test.properties")
                                .setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true));
PropertiesConfiguration config = builder.getConfiguration();
config.setProperty("Id", "3");
builder.save();
System.out.println("config.properties updated Successfully!!");
```

Now one of my key have value like 
`C\://ABC.net\\:1010`.
After modification it becomes 
`C\\://ABC.net\\:1010`. Means it single backslash is converting to two single backslash. Previously I was using common configuration jar 1.10 it that forwardslash also getting change. Now I have used common configuration version
commons-configuration2-2.0.jar. By this version only problem in backslash.

Can any one suggested how to avoid this? I need that after modification single backslash should not convert to doublebackslash.Please note that I don't want to change the property file.

I was following below post to reach till here.
[PropertiesConfiguration - Using "/" in Property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342231/propertiesconfiguration-using-in-property-value/50210811#50210811)

Answer (score 0):

In a properties file, the `:` character is escaped with a single backslash, which is what seems to be happening in your question.

See this question [How do you escape colon (:) in Properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10699055/134894)

which points to the [Properties documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: My Properties file has always value with escape character.C\:ABC.net.But after modification it becomes C\\:ABC.net.I am not modifying this key.I am modifying some other key but this is also changing.I need to prevent this.